# TinyMCE Jquery not working fine

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

Hi I had used `TinyMCE` in my code single page code to upload data into server using `TinyMCE`. My Code is as follows, this is the `add.php` page :

```
<?php

$msg="";
include("config.php");
    if($_POST['title']!= ""){
        $title= $_POST['title'];
        $words= $_POST['words'];
        $words= stripslashes($words);

            if (!$title)
            {
                $msg="Please Enter Title";
            } elseif (!$words)
            {
                $msg="Please enter the Blog";
            }
            $query= mysql_query("INSERT INTO editor (title, content) VALUES ($title, $words)") or die (mysql_error());
            $msg="Success!";
            }
?>

<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add New Blog</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce.min"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tinymce.min"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p><b>Add a New Blog</b></p>
            <form action="add.php" method="post">
                Title of the Blog :
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="title"></input>
                <br/>
                Your Blog :
                <br/>
                <textarea name="words" class="tinymce" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="submit"/> <?php echo $msg; ?>
            </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My `Textarea` is displayed as a normal `textarea`, the data is also not going into the Database.
The `config.php` file is for Database connection and it is working fine, I checked it.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is tinymce initialisation for that text area. I didn't see any javascript code.

Comment: You should use Mysqli http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Hi Pramod, I followed Code from following link :
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUkmxGf-Ldk)
and I only want to implement the add.php page to add the data into the Database. If you know any good implememnted code for WYSWYG editor, I would appreciate if you can share that so that I get an idea on how to implement this. Thanks

Comment: Check now i update my answer with demo proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add New Blog</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            tinymce.init({
                 selector: "textarea"
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p><b>Add a New Blog</b></p>
            <form action="add.php" method="post">
                Title of the Blog :
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="title"></input>
                <br/>
                Your Blog :
                <br/>
                <textarea name="words" class="tinymce" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="submit"/> <?php echo $msg; ?>
            </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Vipin, this actually worked. Thanks a ton man. You resolved my problem. Kudos to you buddy. :)

Answer (score 1):

You **forgot** to **add extension** in **linked script file**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AFm63/)**</kbd>

I think you are added **two TinyMCE library** so it's may be **conflict problem**. So please update only this two library

I am add **only 2 library**

1. JQuery Library - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
2. TinyMCE Library - http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js

And In your **Header add** this script

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
         selector: "textarea"
    });
</script>
```

try now its work.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that,
seriously it is a very silly mistake that I made but the problem isn't yet solved. Even now I am getting the same textarea as before and not the WYSWYG Editor of TinyMCE.
I would appreciate, if you can take another look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, not working. I am still stuck with that old Textarea. I am implementing it first time so I have no clue. Have u implemented this Editor before, I would appreciate if you can share the code.

Comment: I actually tried to follow this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUkmxGf-Ldk), and I just want to use WYSWYG Editor to style up my content and then insert the same in DB.

Comment: No please check my updated answer 100% solve this. you are mistake to add 2 tinymce library so its not work.

Comment: Is your script getting the jquery and tinymce libraries?

Comment: Yaa, I use jquery and tinymce library

Comment: Hello @user1153551, I can see in JSFiddle it is working but it doesn't worked that way, when I used code below by Vipin, it started working, I think its probably because my document wasn't able to fetch the Jquery.
Anyways, you did a lot to help me and all your efforts and methods are truly appreciable. thank You very-very much for your precious time.

Comment: Actually your code didn't worked exactly but you made certain efforts which I really appreciate, however @vipin's code worked as it is, that's why I accepted his but I LIKED your answer. Is there anything I can do more for you?

Comment: and it would have been Injustice with @Vipin if I hadn't Accepted his answer. Sorry but Thanks a ton dear.